# Parse HTML formatted text

Tags: xcode, html-parsing

I am developing a parser using [this](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) wrapper.
The question is: how to extract from HTML formatted text to re-use it again in UIwebview.
As you can see in my code there are "b" and "i" html tags. In "myarray" there are just 123 and 321 without any text. Thanks for your help.
My code:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *html =
    @"<div id=\"all\">"
    "<ul>"
    "<li><b>1</b>23</li>"
    "<li>32<i>1</i></li>"
    "</ul>"
    "</div>";
    HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:html error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }

    HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];

    HTMLNode *mynode = [bodyNode findChildWithAttribute:@"id" matchingName:@"all" allowPartial:TRUE]; 
    NSArray *newsList = [mynode findChildTags:@"li"]; 

    NSMutableArray *myarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (HTMLNode *news in newsList) { // Пробегаем по списку тэгов и выводим новости
        [myarray addObject:[news allContents]];
    }
```

Comment: Please go through this link stackoverflow.com/questions/405749/parsing-html-on-the-iphone

Comment: Read the example give your link

Comment: Thank you, read again my parser source code and found resolution. allContents should be replaced with rawContents.